# Bring up user form when clicking on cell

Tags: excel, vba, popup, userform

I have a spreadsheet with a list of people in the first column and various bits of information about them in the rest of each row. I have a userform which will populate and subsequently edit each record, which I want to have pop up when the user clicks on the person's name.

e.g.:

```
Name        Age    DOB        Postcode
John Smith  55     3/6/1958   RM3 5WO
Mary Jones  22     4/2/1991   RM2 6TP
```

So I want to be able to click on John Smith (A2) to bring up a form with fields for his age, DOB, postcode etc. I also want to be able to use the form to add entries, so it will also function on at least one row below the list.

I've been given the following code to use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
        frm_tch_staffinfo.Show
    End If

End Sub
```

I've tried using this in the sheet, but it doesn't seem to be working - nothing happens when I click on A2. Is there some error in the code or how I've implemented it? (I've put it in the code for the relevant sheet).

Additionally, I want to expand the target address to include the range of all the names (the number of which may change) and at least one cell below (but not the header in A1). Is it possible to define such a range? Either simply selecting A2 and below, or using a process which counts the cells which are full and adds on or more at the end.

Thanks for your help!

ETA:
I definitely require Excel for this, as my usage is that of a spreadsheet rather than a database. This was a simplified example: the data is in fact all numeric and used in relatively complex calculations in other worksheets.

Comment: You are asking for what Ms Access standard delivers. I refer back to my previous reply.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889166/looking-to-build-a-lineup-builder-for-the-site-draftkings-using-excel/18891614?noredirect=1#comment27883994_18891614

Comment: Thanks, but I do need to use Excel: it is definitely a spreadsheet rather than a database. This was a simplified example: the data is in fact all numeric and used in relatively complex calculations in other worksheets.

Comment: I just tried your code and it works just fine for me. Make sure that you put the Worksheet_SelectionChange in the sheet module that is related to the sheet in which the selection change occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comment: the first part of your code works just fine (selection change).
I just did the test and there is nothing wrong with it.
Just note:

- Put the correct form name;
- Place the code in the correct sheet module

As for your second question, the code you are looking for:

```
Set oRange = Range("A1:A10")
If Not Intersect(Target, oRange) Is Nothing Then
    'do something
End If
```

If you want to set the range dynamically, there have been many posts on this before.
Check out for example:
[Getting the actual usedrange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423022/excel-getting-the-actual-usedrange)

Comment: I just restarted excel, and now at least something is happening. (I've had this problem before, actually, where UDFs produced a #NAME? error until I closed and reopened the program. Is that normal?) However, my form isn't working properly but that's something for me to work on. This little bit of code seems ok. Thansk for your help!

Comment: #Name error appears when Excel can't recognize text in a formula. For example, if you type a wrong formula name. This is not related to this sheet event directly.

Comment: I know what the #NAME error is, thanks. What I was saying is that I have created formulae which I know work. But sometimes when I open the sheet they produce the error, then when I restart Excel they work fine once again. Please read what I'm asking first instead of answering what you assume I want and treating me like an idiot.

Comment: I don't see where you get this from. I'm trying to be pure technical here. As I don't have more info on the situation in question (you say when you open the sheet -> is there an event on sheet activation?), I don't see what else I could do than to state what this name error is about.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just got a little frustrated. Basically, I have a sheet with some UDFs. And they work - no typos  & they produce correct values.

Sometimes when I open the sheet they display the correct values at first but if I click in the cell and press return (without changing anything, just updating the field so to speak) it produces a #NAME? error. Then if I restart Excel it doesn't happen and the field goes back to functioning fine.

Given that I can get it working, this is more an irritation than a serious problem, so dw about it too much. Also this probably isn't the thread for it!